# Android:Why These error occur and what are the easy ways to solve them?

Tags: android

I am new to android . I have started off with a instant messaging app for my final year project .But unfortunately its too big for me to do it alone . i come across these errors and i am tired of searching answers for these because for each user the situation varies . My frequently encountered errors are

1)
error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)  activity_main.xml    /Swipe/res/layout  line 27 Android AAPT Problem
2)
R cannot be resolved to a variable .

Note: i have tried to clean my project frequently to update changes but then also i get these errors .

my code sample

```
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/back1"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:text="@string/welcome" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="45sp"/>

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    abdroid:id="@+id/img_clk"
   />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please, write all content of your xml file

Comment: Look @Vijay, we have all learned our ways like that. It's not a worry that you are falling into these errors. As time goes by, you will learn how to handle them on your own without worrying about them.
Since your question is not certain, i would like to know more about the problems that you are facing right now so that we can help you solving them.

Comment: Ya i can understand but i have very less time to do it ..that's the major issue .. anyway i am very happy to see u all responding to me immediately ..thank you and i wish u guys guide me to the right path

Comment: Keep asking Questions, and we will surely help you. Here i found a useful link related to your Final Year Project. https://github.com/realtime-framework/messaging/tree/master/Android
Cheers !

Comment: Thank you sir i have gone through examples like these and i have gained a lot more ideas to implement . I also have a question can we make a layout appear on click of a imageview , i have done the necessary xml code but i want to know how to render a layout ..i created a reference for my imageview in my java file and a onclick event too..how can i proceed further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
abdroid:id="@+id/img_clk"
```

It should read:

```
android:id="@+id/img_clk"
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Error 1**:
Change `abdroid:id="@+id/img_clk"` to `android:id="@+id/img_clk"`

For **Error 2**:
Do a clean Rebuild. If that does not help, check if there is any file starting with a capital letter in your res folder. If there is, change it to a lower case letter.